# External Sitecom Wi-Fi antenna fails to connect to network

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I let the external Sitecom Wi-Fi antenna to works, since the Ubuntu setup.
So the connection has worked properly for many days... until it began to fails, despite all Wi-Fi networks are recognized.

As I had to force some update with Synaptic (mainly regarding kernel, updated to 3.13.0-45), I tried to switch to the previous one (3.13.0-31), but the issue wasn't solved.

I'm not sure if it's a consequence of a bad update, but I did this test.

---

Please help me, my mother needs a stable and "online" PC as it was in the first days, I won't to do newly an OS reinstallation.
Thank you

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for us to trouble shoot it in any way. Open a program called terminal and do these commands: `dmesg` , `sudo lshw -c network`, `iwconfig`, `ifconfig`. Copy output of each command into your question.

Comment: On the drop-down menu on the Network indicator, open "Edit Connections". There should be list of your wifi connections. Try deleting every connection and reconnecting again. Also try restarting the router.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to the internet, try sudo apt-get update. It will ask for your user password, so no worries. Then, sudo apt-get upgrade. Password again.  Try that first as it may just need to update or upgrade your software. Keep us posted.

Comment: As I said, the PC isn't online, and this is the problem. Regarding updates, I did them until a week ago.

Comment: I need the model of your sitecom WiFi antenna.

Comment: You could also try a Linksys wireless network adapter. It plugs into your USB port and runs about $20-$40 USD.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea. Try the Ethernet port on the back of your computer. If working, you should see a connection to *etho0*. If not, we'll talk further. If you are unsure as to how to do this, here are the easy steps:

1. Find the Ethernet port. It looks like a phone jack on the back of your computer, but slightly larger.
2. Connect Ethernet cable, called a CAT5E cable into port, then into router.

Connection should be immediate with a symbol of a small up arrow and down arrow in your tray in the upper right side of the screen. See if it works. Hopefully that helps with your internet connection. We will proceed further after internet connection established.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried connecting to the Internet via the ether net port? See that works attempt updating as Anthony suggests.